# Joda-time daylight savings in Jordan

Tags: timezone, jodatime

I'm hoping somebody can resolve my issue with daylight savings and the country Jordan. According to joda-time 2.2 and 2.3 (at least), Jordan does in fact have daylight savings. My issue however is that there are many websites out there that claim that Jordan has in fact, removed all their daylight savings! Can any body verify for me which of these is correct?

Jordan has daylight savings... Yay, or Nay??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most accurate, well-maintained, well-researched web site I know of for this is [timeanddate.com](http://timeanddate.com).  They have a specific page regarding [Jordan's issues for this year](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/jordan-dst-all-year-2013.html), which says the following:

> The Jordanian government recently announced that the country will continue observing daylight saving time (DST) all year for the second year in a row. The local time in Jordan and its capital Amman is 3 hours ahead of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

It has additional details, which I suggest you read if this is relevant to you.

The confusion you are probably encountering is because they *are* on daylight saving time, but they have cancelled any transitions back to *standard* time, so some may just interpreting that as a new standard time for them.

Joda Time uses the [IANA TZDB](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), which is also very well maintained.  Much of the data on timeanddate.com comes from there anyway.

For Jordan, you should have a time zone id of `Asia/Amman`.  The recent changes for Jordan are reflected in [version 2013f](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2013-September/000014.html).  Joda Time 2.3 shipped with 2013d, so you'll need to manually update to the latest data version following the instructions [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html).

If you'd like to see the specific changes made to the TZDB for Jordan in 2013, you can find them in [this commit](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/5250212e824b4a1de574c2d929e8f087c7553845) in the unofficial sources.